# Integral of a bivariate normal cdf

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let 
$$
\Phi_2(x,y;\rho):=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2+t^2-2st\rho)} \, ds \, dt
$$
be the joint cdf of bi-variate normal random variables with $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and correlation coefficient $\rho$. Is there a way of simplifying
$$
\int_0^Te^{\kappa t}\Phi_2\left(ct+d,ct+d;\frac{t}{T}\right) \, dt
$$
in terms of some well known `special functions'? Here $c,d,T$ and $\kappa$ are constants.

Comment: @ Dilip, the "Abramowitz and Stegun" link redirects me to the current page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say whether you will consider this as a "simplification", but you can start by writing the standard normal bivariate integral as

$$\Phi_2(x,y;\rho)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^y\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}t^2}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2st\rho)}dsdt$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^y\phi\left(\frac {t}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}dsdt$$

For the internal integral we have

$$I_\mathrm{int} = \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}ds-\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}ds$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2+2t\rho s)}ds+\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}ds-\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}ds$$

$$=2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}s^2} \cosh\left[\frac {t\rho}{1-\rho^2}s\right] ds-\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(s^2-2t\rho s)}ds$$

Then you can use the formulas (matching the coefficients appropriately)

[image]

where **please note** that here $\Phi$ is **NOT** the standard normal CDF but the **error function** (**erf**).

Obviously, it is very easy to make an algebraic mistake here, especially when matching coefficients, so go *very* slow. Then bring it all together (some things may simplify), and see how the bivariate standard normal CDF looks like (check also the expression for the error function in terms of the univariate standard normal CDF). Then add one more integral layer and the $cd+t$ arguments you want, and see what further simplifications you can achieve.